# How to share text to whatsapp from email

Tags: html-email, whatsapp

```
<a href="whatsapp://send?text=http://webdevelopmentscripts.com">Share on whatsapp</a>
```

This code is not rendered in email.

I am placing this HTML in blueshift email template.

Comment: "in email" where, in what client? (It's possible that the client is blocking unknown protocols for security reasons.)

Comment: In Gmail it's not rendering, in Mail (Mac) its rendering.

Comment: It's likely a security feature on GMail's end then.